# Delete rows if second column format is not date with sed

Tags: php, mysql, sed

I have some `.gz` files with a `.csv` (comma delimited) file inside.

I am using a php file where I am trying to extract the files and then import the data in a table in mysql.

The second column of the `.csv` files have a date with the format `Y-m-d` (e.g. `2015-10-08`).

Before importing the data of the `.csv` files, I need to delete the rows where the second column is not a date under this format `Y-m-d`.

If the rows do not have a date under this format in the second field, that means that the rows have irrelevant data that I do not need. Check picture below:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I managed to make it work as if the date fields were in the 1st column. In order to do that I just edited the file without changing the filetype or anything else. The code I used and it worked is below :

```
$command = 'zcat '.str_replace(' ', '\ ',$filePath). '| sed \'/^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]/!d\' >' . str_replace(' ', '\ ',$tempFilename);
```

The part that has to be changed is this one :

```
sed \'/^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]/!d\'
```

This one above, deletes all the rows except for the ones that start with a format like 2015-10-10. I do not have to check if the number is an actual date because the .csv files do not have any other information. I tried changing the code to make it work for the second column where the date is :

```
sed \'/[^,]^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]/!d\'
```

Just a note because you might get confused by some symbols in my code -> The code is used in .php files.

Comment: better post some sample input, otherwise we are going to check blindly

Comment: @fedorqui I believe now it is good. I do not have to upload the csv file as a n image. My code works for the 1st column. I want to make it work when the date is in the second column. So, my problem is here : sed \'/^

Comment: I still miss some sample line of your .sql file. The only thing we know about it is that the 2nd column is a date. So what is the delimiter? [edit] and show it.

Comment: @fedorqui I want it to work for comma or tab delimited files. In this example I want to make it work for comma delimited. Then it would be easy to convert the code I guess. I will have to change the ',' to '\t'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like  {Proverbs 18:2 thinking on me, for someone else to not be offended}

```
sed -n '/^[^,]*,[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]/p'
```

Although awk will be better to use with csv files

Comment: In case the .csv file is tab delimited, I guess I have to replace ',' with '\t'.